# Symfony for propert_path for child form type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

I understand if I put

```
        ->add('visitor.name', TextType::class, [
            'property_path' => 'vistorName'
        ])
```

This will be identical to `<input name="vistorName"`

How can I do similar for child form, to have all the child field as a parent field name without putting in as a child array.

```
        $builder->add('customer', CustomerType::class);
```

CustomerType

```
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('phone', PhoneNumberType::class, [
            'default_region' => 'GB', // TODO GLOBAL release
            'format' => PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL
        ]);
```

The above form should generate `<input name="name"... <input name="email"...` and ***not*** as following  `<input name="customer[name]"...`

how can I do that?

Following is complete code example

```
// Cart model
class Cart {

    protected $productName;

    /** @var Customer */
    protected $customer;
}

// Customer model
Class Customer {

    protected $name;

    protected $email;

    protected $phone;
}


//CustomerType form
$builder
    ->add('name', TextType::class)
    ->add('email', EmailType::class)
    ->add('phone', PhoneNumberType::class, [
        'default_region' => 'GB', // TODO GLOBAL release
        'format' => PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL
    ]);


// main parent form

class MainFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('productName', TextType::class)
            ->add('customer', CustomerType::class); // need property_path for this, so all the inner fields can be used as parent
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Cart::class,
            'required' => false
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'cart';
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Symfony Forms is not Bruce Almighty. I think, we are currently using vue.js to do exactly what you require. I'll ask the guy who was implementing this.

Comment: Can you upload the main parent form with the configuration options?

Comment: @albert added full version

Answer (score 1):

It works the other way around:

Scenario:

VisitorEntity:

- TypeOfVisitorEntity
- CustomerEntity

Now you want to update a VisitorEntity customer.name:

```
class MainFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('productName', TextType::class)
            ->add('customerName', TextType::class, ['property_path'=>'customer.name'])
            ->add('customerEmail', TextType::class, ['property_path'=>'customer.email'])
            ->add('customerPhone', TextType::class, ['property_path'=>'customer.phone'])
    ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Cart::class,
            'required' => false
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'cart';
    }
}
```

## property_path

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path

type: any default: the field's name

Fields display a property value of the form's domain object by default. When the form is submitted, the submitted value is written back into the object.

**If you want to override the property that a field reads from and writes to, you can set the property_path option. Its default value is the field's name.**

If you wish the field to be ignored when reading or writing to the object you can set the property_path option to false, but using property_path for this purpose is deprecated, you should use the mapped option.

Comment: how can I do same for CustomerType form without writing the whole form inside parent form?

Comment: That it is the point of the property_path you do not need to create subforms. If you update your question with your entities and forms I will update my answer with your code

Comment: added a full example — I have not used the original complete code, because the customerType form is too big and too complicated for here, so I just replaced it with a simple example.

Comment: So it's not possible to assign these inside child form? (have to import all the code in parent form)